# How can I make a fixed div go across parent element without covering vertical scroll?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a dictionary that you can search through. I want the search bar to follow you as you scroll but the scroll bar gets covered up by the search bar. So I want the search bar the size of the containing div but I don't want it to cover the scroll bar.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tombatan/moLwjh9m/1/

I think the main problem would be in this code:

```
.lgPopup {
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border:5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
width:500px;
margin:0 auto;
max-height:700px;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
}

#searchBlock {
width:inherit;
display:block;
background-color:white;
padding-bottom:10px;
border-bottom:1px solid rgba(173, 173, 173, 0);
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="lgPopup" id="dicPopup">
    <h2 class="popupHead">Dictionary</h2>

    <form id="searchBlock">
         <input type="text" name="word" size="5" maxlength="5" id="searchWord" placeholder="Search Word" />
         <div class="button" id="searchButton">Submit</div>
    </form>
    <p class="popupBody" id="dicText"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the search bar to always stick to the top?

```
.lgPopup {

    position:fixed;

...
}
```

Comment: I had it so if you scroll down a certain amount it would change to fixed. That's in the JS in jsfiddle. It's when it turns fixed it covers part of the scroll bar.

Comment: I would just make the searchBlock 20px narrower. Your main container is 500px, make searchBlock: 480px; http://jsfiddle.net/moLwjh9m/12/

Comment: I was hoping for a cleaner solution than that but I guess it works, Thx